# Neutral D meson decay widths from dimensional analysis of feynman vertices

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-analysis, weak-interaction

I know the decay width of a process is proportional to the interaction strengths at the vertices, and for a $D^0\to \pi^+\pi^-$ where $D^0=\bar{u}c, ~ \pi^+=u\bar{d}, ~\pi^-=u\bar{d}$, the decay involves a $W^+$ boson, such that the charmed quark decays into a down quark, and the $W^+$ decays into an antidown and an up.

The interaction vertices must then be  $g_w\cos(\theta_c)$ and $g_w\sin(\theta_c)$ at the W boson to up and anti down quark and charmed to down vertex respectivley.

How would you combine these to do a dimensional analysis of the decay width - would it be $\Gamma(D^0\to \pi^+\pi^-)\propto g_w^4\sin^2(\theta_c)\cos^2(\theta_c)m_D^5$?

**EDIT**
in my lecture notes $g_w=\sqrt{G_F}$ sorry for confusion

Comment: for starters, you are missing the pion decay constant and the $W$ boson mass.

Comment: Is that not included in $g_w$? How would i incorporate those into it?

Comment: no, that is not included in $g_w$. It is included in the Fermi constant $G_F\sim g_w^2/m_W^2$.

Comment: i thought $g_w=\sqrt{G_F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, given the above structural input that $\Gamma(D^0\to \pi^+\pi^-)\propto G_F^2 \sin^2(\theta_c)\cos^2(\theta_c)$, Rayleigh's method of dimensional analysis encourages you to fill in the missing five dimensionful powers for dimensional consistency: the rate has a single mass, and the Fermi constant squared deducts four powers of the mass.

Here, the dominant mass is that of the *D*, and that of the pion products is insignificant; so, barring extreme dynamical suppressions, the first suspect will have to be the only remaining mass scale, 
$$\Gamma \propto G_F^2  \sin^2(\theta_c)\cos^2(\theta_c)m_D^5 ~. $$

This is quite similar to the likewise weak decay of the  μ,
by the very same logic,
$$\Gamma_\mu \propto G_F^2  m_\mu ^5 ~. $$

Comment: The $m^5$ scaling can be seen very clearly in any $M, \Gamma$ logplot of catalogued particles. http://a.rivero.nom.es/research/nonstrong.jpg